# Dynamically print ul id name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
var currentulid=data;

$("#header #my).prepend('<li>New list </li>');
```

I am designing a nested comment system using jsp+jquery . I need to assign ul id dynamically.In below code , instead of #my , i need to get variable currentulid , there.

is something like ,

```
$("#header currentulid).prepend('<li>New list </li>');
```

i hvae tried using console to print value there, but its not working. please suggest me a way to acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `+` to concatenate any variable with string in jquery. Try:

```
$("#header #"+currentulid).prepend('<li>New list </li>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string concatenation,

```
$("#header "+currentulid)
```

if `currentulid` does not include `#`

```
$("#header #"+currentulid)
```

---

or context based selector

```
$("#"+currentulid, "#header")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#header ' + '#' + currentulid).prepend('<li>New list </li>');
```

You can write your **selector** as a **string**, then to pass to **jquery function**.

Or use the version with context.

> jQuery( selector [, context ] )
>
> context Type: Element or jQuery A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to
>   use as context

```
$('#'+currentulid, '#header')
```